# recursively determine similarity in lucene

Tags: java, lucene, similarity, recursive-query, tf-idf

I have a collection of books in multiple languages. I need to link parts of each book to each other based on their similarity. I need to link books to similar books, chapters to similar chapters and subchapters to similar subchapters.

Preferably, the similarity measure would also take into account how similar the next highest level are, so when I want to compare two chapters, it would first check how similar the books the chapters belong to are to each other and use that as a baseline. I suppose this part I will have to implement manually, but I'm wondering how to do the hierarchical linking effectively.

Is there a way to tell lucene that the documents in an index follow a hierarchical structure where books are composed of chapter and chapters are composed of subchapters (which are the actual documents to store)? If so, books and chapters could be constructed at runtime by combining the documents they are composed of. Does lucene have a way to do this?

One simple alternate approach would be to create separate indices for each level of resolution, i.e. one for books, one for chapters and one for subchapters. But this seems inelegant and I'm not sure if this would work well, considering that I would get different inverse-document-frequency values in the different indices. This leads to a secondary question: is there a way to make lucene only consider certain documents as a reference class for its tf-idf calculations?

Answer (score 0):

If number of levels is predetermined then you may use grouping functionality http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/grouping/org/apache/lucene/search/grouping/package-summary.html

I do not know if it works with multiple-value fields, if yes then it could address also multiple levels of grouping (hierarchy similarity). You may of course use different fields for different levels.

There is also another approach which I experienced - grouping document ID's in fast NoSQL database and when lucene returns document you may search ID's of similar documents in NoSQL and then back in lucene. However, such approach may lead to other issues (i.e. number of total hits, because lucene returns total hits even without returning the results, but grouping shall most probably change that number.